# FFMPEG unexpected behavior inside nodejs Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to burn subtitles into a video using FFMPEG. I'm working within a serverless lambda architecture, and we've used FFMPEG with lambda by using layers before and everything worked okay.
Now I'm trying to burn subtitles inside a video using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i https://some-bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/my-video.mp4 -f mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt subtitled-video.mp4
```

The issue is, that command works perfectly inside my local machine or any other instance I try. However inside my lambda function, I just get the original video without the subtitles.
At first I thought it could be the ffmpeg build I was using, but after trying wiht it, it worked in every other environment I tried.

Also I don't get any error in the output from the ffmpeg job inside lambda, everything seeems to work okay. Just that it doesn't burn the subtitles

I hope you can help me with this issue. Or at least point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the `sub.srt` file stored? Presumably it is in the `/tmp/` directory? Try using a full path to reference the file.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for the idea, actually It's in the root of the lambda directory, I tried running the command $cat sub.srt inside the lambda fuction, to validate the path was right, and it worked. Also when I put a wrong sub file path, it outputs an error indicating ffmpeg couldn't locate the subtitles file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda truncates the log, and you are only seeing the end of the logs. If there is a warning message in the middle of the log, you won't be able to see it.

I'm working on the same issue and the bug I found is that there is no font. For EC2 instance and Lambda functions, if you don't supply a font, there is no system font like your local machine does.

If there is no font, the ffmpeg command won't be able to generate the captions.

My solution is

1. Add fonts and font config to your Lambda layer
2. Add environment variable (FONTCONFIG_PATH) to your lambda function so that it knows where to find the fonts. The value should be the folder where your fonts reside. In my case, it is /opt/fonts since that's how I bundled my Lambda layer.
3. Add a forced style to your subtitles spec

   subtitles=sample.srt:force_style="FontName=ArialUnicodeMS"

Hope it helps you solving the problem.